# How to use pixi.js with gulp and webpack including FXAA

Tags: gulp, webpack, pixi.js

I just started pixi.js and it seems marvelous!
But I can't make it totally work with Gulp and WebPack...

On Chrome (Mac), everything work but on Safari (iPhone) i get this error: `fs.readFileSync is not a function` from `function FXAAFilter`.
I get the same error on desktop when I use `forceFXAA: true`.

My gulp scripts task :

```
gulp
    .src(config.scripts.src)
    .pipe(gulp_webpack({
        node: {
            fs: "empty"
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /(nodes_modules)/,
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    query: {
                        presets: ["es2015"]
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.json$/,
                    loader: "json"
                }
            ],
            postLoaders: [
                {
                    include: path.resolve(__dirname, "nodes_modules/pixi.js"),
                    loader: "transform?brfs"
                }
            ]
        },
    }))
    .pipe(gulp_concat(config.scripts.out))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.scripts.dst));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because webpack includes the actual file operation (that should be run at compile time) that is used to include WebGL frag files into the JS bundle. My guess is that you only see the error on environments where PIXI uses the GL renderer.

Try `npm install transform-loader brfs --save` and add the following to your config:

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: "./index.js",
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "transform?brfs"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/webpack/transform-loader

Comment: why it didn't work for me? Can you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608118/uncaught-typeerror-fs-readfilesync-is-not-a-function